# Flask, where is the specified static_folder?

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

Now, I have a project source code, and in this project there is a statement:

`APP = Flask(__name__, static_folder='../statics')`

Where is the folder `'../statics'`?

Answer (score 2):

In Flask the **static** folder is usually placed (also by default) in the root path of the application and it is named as *"static"*.

It looks that in your project your **static** folder is placed in the parent directory of your application directory and it is named as *"statics"*

You will find more information about the applications parameters [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object).

To know more about the static folder you can also check [this documentation](http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html).